# skimage.io - undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs

Tags: python, intel-mkl

I try to import skimage.io and have the following error:
...mkl/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs

I have an mkl lib in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, if I delete it than I have:
ImportError: libmkl_rt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you installed all of the necessary packages? i.e scipy, numpy, six, dateutil, cython, pyparsing?

Comment: Yeap, everything installed

Answer (score 0):

on my workstation, it is the problem with `libiomp5.so`. You can find the location of the so file with command (i.e. `sudo find / -name libiomp5.so` on Linux) and add the directory of its location to `etc/ld.so.conf.d/intel_mkl_settings.conf` right after the MKL installation directory(`/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64`). That helps specify the location of `omp` library. Hope this helps.